# UWP AdaptiveTrigger minWindowWidth background not changing

Tags: .net, xaml, xamarin, uwp

I'm learning UWP and having the below code not working:

```
<Page
    x:Class="LearningUWP.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:LearningUWP"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid>
        <Grid>
            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <VisualStateGroup>
                    <VisualState>
                        <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                            <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="500" />
                        </VisualState.StateTriggers>

                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Target="myStackPanel.Background" Value="Red" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

            <StackPanel x:Name="myStackPanel" Background="Blue" >
                <TextBlock Text="myTextBlock" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

I'm expecting the background turns to red when the window `width > 500`. However, it doesn't work when expanding it. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First move it to the top `Grid`.

Second, you probably want to add the `Setter` for `MinWindowWidth="0"`